# white screen appeared when i use anchor tag href in mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

i have a anchor tag to load a view like below

```
<a href="@Url.Action(Convert.ToString(ViewBag.returnUrl), Convert.ToString(ViewBag.returnUrl), new { hello=""},Request.Url.Scheme)" class="bkpbutton">Back</a>
```

it looks like below when it is rendered,

```
<a href="http://localhost:42711/controller/action" class="bkpbutton ui-link">Back</a>
```

but some times it is flickering and showing a white screen instead of rendering view of the action method.

Comment: I'd guess ViewBag.returnUrl is emtpy sometimes making the url "broken"?

Comment: no Daniel, ViewBag.rerurnUrl is always having values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with jquery mobile navigation.
added rel="external" to anchor tag and it is resolved the issue.